# Why do I get "LoadLibrary failed with error 1114: a dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed"?

Tags: java, dll, applet, runtime-error

When I run my java application program an error window appears saying that

> "LoadLibrary failed with error 1114: a dynamic link library (DLL) >initialization routine failed".

I have tested my code on a different machine and it worked perfectly.The program shows a PApplet window with a map inside.However, Running the code on my laptop, the PApplet appears and all of the sudden the DLL error stops the rest from being shown.

What the problem could be and how can I fix it?

Here is the code I am trying to run. It is worth to mention that it runs successfully if I remove what's inside the `setup()` method.

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class LifeExpectancy2 extends PApplet {

UnfoldingMap map;
    public void setup()
      {
        size(800,600,OPENGL);
        map = new UnfoldingMap (this, 50, 50, 700, 500, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher (this, map);
}
    public void draw()
     {

      }

}
```

Comment: Your Java applications depend on a DLL which either doesn't exist on your laptop or is not at the expected location. Which DLL? We can't know. As we don't know your application. So without further information from you we can only guess.

Comment: @SubOptimal The application itself uses the Processing java library which I have already installed. I can't think of any other libraries than my application might be using. Would that been a library that is supposed to be included in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after I installed my Netbeans to build some projects in PHP and it was fixed changing some graphics options in the control painel of my Windows 10.

Take a look on this video and see if it fixs your issue as well:
[Windows 10 - Java Loadlibrary Error 1114](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AL3ayVu98Vw) 
I hope it can be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Which Unfolding version did you download? You seem to use some Java IDE (and not Processing's one) so you need the Unfolding-for-Eclipse distribution which includes all needed native libraries (i.e. also the DLL in question).

For the records, the DLL is the native library for Windows OS to bind Java to the OpenGL API (JOGL).